# Como usar funções de agregação em um WHERE?

Tags: banco-de-dados, query, sqlite

Estou fazendo um trabalho da faculdade sobre Banco de Dados, e uma das `Query` que devo fazer é essa:

- Mostrar todos os credores que tiveram um total de compras maior do
  que R$ 5000,00;

Tentei:

```
SELECT NomeCredor, SUM(Compras.Valor)

FROM Credores, Compras

WHERE (idCredores = Compras.Credores_idCredores)

AND (SUM(Compras.Valor)) > 5000

GROUP BY NomeCredor

ORDER BY NomeCredor;
```

O problema é que o `SUM(Compras.Valor)` não pode ser passado como uma condição do `WHERE`. Alguém sabe uma alternativa?

Answer (score 3):

Tente utilizar a cláusula HAVING após o Group By, muito parecida com o WHERE, porém faz a verificação da condição dentro do agrupamento.

[Excelente referência sobre HAVING em SQLite](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_having_clause.htm).

Comment: Boa João, creio que sua resposta é a correta!

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado. Lerei sobre a cláusula HAVING.